# Representation of parent-child relationship in java

Tags: algorithm, relationship

I have a set of tables that are related (parent child relationships).

I need a solution where in I can quickly find if two tables are related. 
Also If they are related I need to find out if the relationship is a parent-child relationship or child-parent relationship.

**My solution:**

Store the relationship details in the form of a matrix.

Say there are three tables T1, T2 and T3. T1 has two children T2 and T3.

Then I can represent the relationship as

```
{{0,1,1},
 {-1,0,0},
 {-1,0,0}}
```

The first row and first column represent T1.
The second row and second column represent T2.
The third row and third column represent T3.

To find the relationship between T1 and T2 you go to the first row and second column. The value is 1. This shows that T1 is the parent and T2 is the child.

A -1 would indicate that the first table is the child and the second table is the parent.

A 0 would indicate that the two tables are not related.

**Is there a better solution to this problem?**

Comment: Depending on how many relationships exist, you could get a sparse matrix where many entries are 0 and only few not. Then it would be better memory-wise to store a list (array, ArrayList...) of childs and an ID (ID number, java object reference etc.) of the parent together with each table entity.

Comment: @deviantfan Wouldn't that be more time consuming? I'm looking for a solution that is fast. Memory is not a problem for me.

Comment: @Holger You're right. Alexey has made the change in the tags.

Comment: Yes. With the right data structures, you can reduce it to (bestcase) constant time again (hashset-something), but alltogether it will be a bit slower than your matrix (single 2d-array-access...). But 1: Compare what´s better. With ~1000 Entitys, each has 1 parent and 3 childs (for example), your matrix will have 1Mio entries, my suggestion only 4000 (+some overhead for the management, but still...). But 2: If this little speed difference is a problem, don´t use java in the first place.